# How do I deal with the classification output when training a semi-supervised SWWAE in keras?

Tags: keras

I'm playing with the SWWAE example, and I put a classification head onto the end of the encoder.  I'm running it as both a supervised classifier and an encoder/decoder and it's working fine.  However, I'm unsure how to run it in semi-supervised mode.  I was thinking that for unlabeled data, I could just set all the output labels to 0?  If I understand correctly, for categorical cross entropy, this should mean that there's no error signal to propagate.  Is that correct?  In this case would I need to make batches of data where each item in the batch is either all unlabeled or all labeled?